# How to set "keys_only" using googledatastore package

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-dataflow

I want to read from datastore using googledatastore package on GoogleCloudDataFlow.

But, I cannot find "keys_only" query on googledatastore document.
http://googledatastore.readthedocs.io/en/latest/googledatastore.html

How to set "keys_only" on googledatastore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use projection query

```
  from googledatastore import helper
  helper.add_projection(
    query,
    '__key__')
```